java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: SHA1withRSA
Need to set useSSL=true for mysql cloud connection for jdbc connect string but getting this error.
SHA1withRSA has been restricted in our environment. How do I resolve this
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: SHA1withRSA
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.check(AlgorithmChecker.java:231)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:1553)

[wrapped] java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:1557)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:1484)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1431)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:631)

[wrapped] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:647)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:467)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:363)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:393)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:476)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:447)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:347)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:194)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:101)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:308)

[wrapped] com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:317)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:204)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1369)

    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:133)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:949)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:819)

[wrapped] com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:242)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:374)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:106)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:649)

[wrapped] java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
I am using dbsql of symmetricds to connect Azure mysql database and expecting successful connection.

You will need to edit the java.security specification file for you JDK, and allow SHA1 algorithm for the certificate path:
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, 
RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 
SHA1 usage SignedJAR & denyAfter 2019-01-01
Remove the SHA1 entries to allow SHA1 algorithm.
